# Storyboard issue with UINavigationController and UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I always make my apps using `Storyboard`. But at the moment he is giving me some difficulties.
You can see a screenshot of my storyboard below here.

The problem is situated in the right hand corner. There I have a `UItableview` in my viewcontroller. When I push on a cell. I do a push segue to the next view. But when I this my tabbar at the bottom disappears.

Also in the view with my `UItableview` I defined a left and a right bar button inside my `navigationbar`. When I segue those two buttons disappears also and I get a back button (and I want those two buttons back from the previous viewController and get rid of the backbutton.)

How I can fix this problem??

I have tried this:

```
 self.tabBarController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
```

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards

[image]

Comment: I suppose you need a Navigation controller before the UITableView, i.e. after the UITabBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always used separate `NavigationController`'s for each branch of a `TabBarController`.  This may be causing your problem.  Try embedding a Nav Controller in each of the 4 `ViewController`s hooked to the `TabBarController`.

Also, make sure to call:

```
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

After `viewDidLoad` in the `ViewController` you want this behavior.  Then AFTER you call this, you will need to instantiate the two buttons you want to use instead.

EDIT - Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276836/ios-5-segue-not-working-after-the-first-execution/9277472#9277472) for an example of using a `Protocol` and Delegation to login your user.

Comment: When I do it like this. I get two navigation bars below each other.

Comment: I don't have my first navigation controller before my TabBarController.

Comment: Yes, but I need to have it like this because I have a login flow before the tabbar comes in.

Comment: Use a modal segue instead of push and use delegation to dismiss that VC and segue to the TabBarController (home screen) when the user logs in successfully.  I can amend my answer with an example if you need.

Comment: If you have an example it would be nice.

Comment: No prob. About to leave for work. Will post example after I get there.

Comment: Gave you a link to an example.